# binomial coefficents and composite numbers

Tags: number-theory

Given a binomial coefficient

$${n \choose k}$$

With $n>3$ and $k\neq 1$ or $n-1$, is the binomial cofficient always a composite number?

Comment: I assume you mean $k\not\in\{0,1,n,n-1\}$, in which case the answer is yes.

Comment: Is it a well known result? I would like to see it.